# sql select multiple values from when id

Tags: mysql, sql

here is how looks like my table:

```
fid  | section  | baseData
59   |    58    |  somedata
59   |    58    |  somedata
60   |    58    |  somedata
```

I need to get data like this:

owner, name, email

All values are in table baseData, but owner is fid=59, name is fid 70, email is fid 71

So I would like to get:

```
 owner       |  name       |  email
 owner_name  |  user_name  | user_email
 owner_name2 |  user_name2 | user_email2
```

I'm trying in this way:

```
SELECT fid, 
(CASE 
WHEN (fid = 59 AND section = 58)
THEN baseData
END) AS owner
FROM sobipro_field_data
WHERE section = 58 GROUP BY fid
```

but getting only nulls

what I'm trying to get is:

```
When fid = 59 -> select baseData as owner
When fid = 70 -> select baseData as name
When fid = 71 -> select baseData as email
```

Comment: I have no clue how the first table and last SQL relate to your desired output.

Comment: I read this few times but really did not understand what you really are looking at

Comment: Do you mean you're using one column (fid) to associate three columns (owner, name and email)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one section:

```
SELECT  
    max(CASE WHEN (fid = 59) THEN baseData ELSE null END) AS owner,  
    max(CASE WHEN (fid = 70) THEN baseData ELSE null END) AS name,  
    max(CASE WHEN (fid = 71) THEN baseData ELSE null END) AS email  
FROM sobipro_field_data  
WHERE section = 58;
```

For each section:

```
SELECT section,
    max(CASE WHEN (fid = 59) THEN baseData ELSE null END) AS owner,  
    max(CASE WHEN (fid = 70) THEN baseData ELSE null END) AS name,  
    max(CASE WHEN (fid = 71) THEN baseData ELSE null END) AS email  
FROM sobipro_field_data  
group by section;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  
(CASE WHEN (fid = 59 AND section = 58) THEN baseData END) AS owner,  
(CASE WHEN (fid = 70 AND section = 58) THEN baseData END) AS name,  
(CASE WHEN (fid = 71 AND section = 58) THEN baseData END) AS email  

FROM sobipro_field_data  

Cheers!
```